# Ionic 3 Cordova Geolocation plugin not working on Android and browser

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I can’t get the Ionic Cordova Geolocation plugin to work on Android or on browsers, though the same code works on iOS. The `getCurrentPosition` method can’t access the location even after I’ve given permission.
On Android, the `getCurrentPosition` never returns unless I add a timeout parameter, after which it returns the error “Timeout expired.”
I've tried it on Android emulator and on actual devices (running OS 6 and 7), Chrome and Safari, none of which work.

Here is my Ionic/system info:

- @ionic/cli-utils : 1.12.0
- ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0
- cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
- @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
- Cordova Platforms : android 6.2.3 browser 4.1.0 ios 4.4.0
- Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.6.1
- cordova-plugin-geolocation: 2.4.3
- OS : OS X El Capitan

I've tried these (and more variations):

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              private geolocation: Geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.onSuccess, this.onError, {timeout:5000});

}

onSuccess(position) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(position));
}

onError(error) {
  alert('code: '+ error.code+ '\n'+'message: '+error.message + '\n');
}
```

`getCurrentPosition` method:

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({timeout:5000}).then((pos : Geoposition) => {
  alert(pos+" : " +JSON.stringify(pos));
}.catch((err : PositionError)=>{
  alert("error : " + err.message);
});
```

Both give the same/similar results, as described above.

Comment: You **cannot** use it inside the `browser` since it is a `Cordova plugin`.

Comment: try to call the plugin within `this.platform.ready().then(()=>{})`

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it, but same result

Comment: Did you get any solution to this problem?